# Consider the region bounded by the positive y-axis…

Tags: integration, limits, area

> Consider the region $D$ bounded by the positive $y$-axis, the line $y=8$ and the line $y=x^3$. Evaluate the following integral between $x=0$ and $x=2$.
>   $$\iint_D \frac{x^3y^2}4\ dx\ dy$$

What are the limits and what is the solution? I've asked people and they all give conflicting ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AOrtiz is exactly correct, but another way to determine for yourself is to examine the region of integration by sketching the given bounds:

[image]

From here you can see clearly see that the limits of integration are $0\le x\le 2$ and $x^3\le y\le8$. It follows then that $$\int_0^8 \int_0^{y^{1/3}}\frac{x^3y^2}{4}dx\,dy=\int_0^2\int_{x^3}^8\frac{x^3y^2}{4}dy\,dx$$

Comment: Ah this is good to see! - i think i am having an issue with timing when to substitute the limits in and swapping them around, How do i write expressions as you are? i could type in what i'm doing and we could troubleshoot! :)

Comment: Here is a link to a Mathjax tutorial; this is the typeset that the site uses. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it one step at a time. We want to compute the integral of $\iint_D \frac{x^3y^2}{4}\,dA$, where $D$ is the region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves $x = 0$ on the left, $y = 8$ on the top, and $y = x^3$ on the right. Our first step is to determine whether we want to integrate with respect to $\,dx\,dy$ or $\,dy\,dx$. Either one works in this instance since the integrand is bounded and continuous apart from a set of measure zero (this is technical stuff, and nothing to worry about when it comes to what follows---just adding it for completeness).

Let's contemplate how we might integrate with respect to $\,dy\,dx$ first. That is, we are choosing a slice parallel to the $y$-axis and looking at our bounds of integration as $y$ goes from bottom to top. Eventually we are going to have to perform this "inner integral" over the slice, but we know that we are going to have to "sweep" this slice along with an integral over $x$, too. So, we can look and see what our bounds of $x$ are going to be. From the picture in Ethan Hunt's answer, we see that $x$ goes from $x=0$ to $x=2$. So, we have

$$
\int_{x=0}^{x=2}(\text{something})\,dx,
$$

where $\text{something}$ is itself the integral along the slice parallel to the $y$-axis for a fixed $x$. Inspecting this slice, we see that the bottom-most $y$-bound is not a fixed number for every choice of $x$ between $0$ and $2$. Instead, the bound is the curve $y = x^3$. So, just like when we integrate between constant bounds, we will integrate with this *curve* as our lower bound. The upper bound is the flat ceiling $y = 8$. So, writing this out:

$$
\int_{x=0}^{x=2}\left(\int_{y=x^3}^{y=8}\text{integrand}\,dy\right)\,dx.
$$

Notice that the bounds on the inner integral are represented with $y$ going from its bottom bound, the curve $y = x^3$ to its upper bound $y = 8$. The actual process of performing the integrals is now routine single-variable integration, treating $x$ as a constant when performing the inner single-variable integral over $y$.

The computation is the same:

$$
\int_{x=0}^{x=2}\left(\int_{y=x^3}^{y=8}\frac{x^3y^2}{4}\,dy\right)\,dx = \frac{1}{4}\int_{x=0}^{x=2}x^3\left(\int_{y=x^3}^{y=8} y^2\,dy\right)\,dx = \frac{1}{4}\int_{x=0}^{x=2}x^3\left[\frac{y^3}{3}\right]_{y = x^3}^{y = 8}\,dx \\= \frac{1}{12}\int_0^2 x^3(8^3 - x^9)\,dx = \frac{1}{12}\int_0^2 (8^3x^3 - x^{12})\,dx = \frac{1}{12}(\frac{2^4\cdot8^3}{4} - \frac{1}{13}2^{13}) = \frac{3\cdot2^9}{13}\approx 118.153846154.
$$

Try writing your integral with respect to $dx\,dy$ using the method I outlined above and compare with what I get here. The new bounds are $0 \leq x \leq y^{1/3}$ and $0 \leq y \leq 8$, whence your integral is

$$
\int_0^8\int_0^{y^{1/3}}\tfrac{1}{4}x^3y^2\,dx\,dy = \frac{1}{16}\int_0^8y^2y^{4/3}\,dy = \frac{1}{16}\int_0^8y^{10/3}\,dy = \frac{3}{13\cdot 16}(8^{13/3}) = \frac{3\cdot 2^9}{13} \approx 118.153846154.
$$

Comment: Hi there thank you for the fast reply!

Comment: It seems clearer to me what's going on, however could you possibly speak through the steps ? i'm unfortuantley very new to math and cant see whats going on, it seems to only be this typing of question i'm having resistance with, How do you get this x3(83−x9)dx? thank you so very much!

Comment: @Sam I have added an additional step in each evaluation. Practice evaluating each of the single-variable integrals, and see if you can get your answer to look like mine.

Comment: How may i write the expressions as you have shown them? i'd like to type in my method here so you can troubleshoot :)

Comment: @Sam Here is the MathJax tutorial for typesetting equations. It's good to learn as soon as possible! http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Sam you can also right-click on the math in my answer and select "Show math as" >> "TeX commands" to see how I typeset it.

Comment: Awesome thanks! just one added question, What is the rule on swapping y=x^3 for y^1/3 ?   again apologise for my lack in foundation maths!

Comment: @Sam, notice that the region is bounded on the right by the function $f$ whose equation is $y = x^3$. Thus, this is the same graph as the function whose equation is $y^{1/3} = x$. When we integrate with respect to $x$, we are acknowledging that $x$ goes from $x = 0$, to the graph of the function $f$, and we express points on that graph in terms of $x$ by saying that $x = y^{1/3}$ everywhere on that graph. For instance, at $y = 8$, $x = y^{1/3} = 8^{1/3} = 2$.

Comment: Oh i see, that will be helpful! thankyou!

Comment: I still cant seem to get my head around the answer, is there any possibility you may express it in very simple terms without missing many steps? again i apologise, my math education started at university level - my foundations of the subject are awful :(, as soon as i see it written differently my mind explodes!

Comment: @Sam are you struggling with the bounds or performing the integrals?

Comment: I understand how to integrate i think my issue is... When or how to input the integrals, if we had the limits all as numbers i'm certain i could solve this problem easily

Comment: @Sam, if the fact is that you are struggling with the bounds being functions, try to think of the functions as "general numbers". I will update my answer if you are still struggling after trying to puzzle through the integral. Maybe consider the simpler problem $\iint_D 1 \,dx\,dy$, and integrate that first. That is, instead of integrating the function $x^3y^2/4$, integrate something simpler and try to really understand the logic behind those bounds and the order of integration. Also, use google and Khan Academy to your advantage.

Comment: Hello agian, ive tried a number of problems from youtube and such but i still cant see where i am going wrong, i am getting stupidly large numbers so i assume i'm overdoing something. Would it be possible to go through the simple steps to iron out any creases ? thank you again!

Comment: have i got this right when i say i do the int of (x^3)/4 for dx and the int of (y^2)/4 for dy?

Comment: @Sam, check my edited answer. I have added a whole component that may help you answer that question as well as give you insight into what is going on.

Comment: i understand untill   after the 3rd '=' sign along under the title "the computation is the same"   i think im having issues seeing where something it switched, for example when y is switched for x^3 or vise versa?

Comment: Just as a comparison could i ask another similar question with a few differences?   This is it here: 

" Consider the region D bounded by the positive y axis, the line y=1 and the line y = x^2. Evaluate the following integral over the interval  x=0 to 1.     ( Double integral of ) 3x^2 dA

Comment: @Sam I have modified my answer to be even more explicit. It would serve you well to study what I have here and to practice on the problem you have invented, which is a great way for you to practice the ideas I have presented here.

Comment: That's perfect! i got it first time with that and can see what you doing! i can also see how/why you shorten it it does make a lot of sense haha! thank you very much for your extended time it really helped! i'll try the other problem also!

Comment: @Sam wonderful! You could upvote my answer if it helped you. Try to do it with respect to $dx\,dy$ as well. Then practice with the problem you made up, doing it with respect to $dx\,dy$ and $dy\,dx$.

Comment: Yes i certainly will! being very new to this level of maths having it spoon fed is needed at the moment but i'm sure ill improve! thanks again!